# How to give the spinner for tabs while data is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

```js
function happening(){
  $(".spinner").show();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?=base_url()?>timeline/timeline_v2_ajax",
    async:false,
    cache:false,
    error: function() {
      console.log('Something is wrong');
    },
    success: function(msg){
      $(".spinner").hide();
      $('#default-tab-1').html(msg);
      App.init();
      FormPlugins.init();
    }
  });
}

var LandingPage = function() {
  "use strict";
  return {
    init: function() {
      $('#default-tab-1').html('<span class="spinner"></span>');
      happening();
    }
  }
}() 

$(document).ready(function() {
  LandingPage.init();
  WhattodoPage.init();
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#default-tab-1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="semi-bold">What is happening ?</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="" id="what-to-do">
        <a href="#default-tab-2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="semi-bold">What to do ?</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <div class="tab-content"> 
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="default-tab-1"></div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="default-tab-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two tabs, here i want to display the spinner for the body of the tab while data is loading in both tabs. above is my code, in that i have included the spinner in script but it's not working. can anyone please help me. any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Console error ? ajax return data successfully ?  **Not working** doesn't say much .

Comment: please share your spinner css here

Comment: Go to Inspect Element and check this div "default-tab-1" has spinner html or not.
If default-tab-1 has spinner html then it means your javascript code is working fine.
problem is in css

Comment: Thanku all for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the ".spinner" class first. i.e. is this class has proper attributes to display anything or not.